# Conditional Join SQL how to join

Tags: sql, left-join

I am working on SQl and I have two tables table 1 and table 2.  I would like to join on a column called product that sometimes have no matches on the other table but may have a match on a different column. if a row in table1 has no match in second table, then I would like to join on another column. Is this possible to do a conditional join?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want in the result set?

Comment: *"I am working on Oracle SQl"* Then please don't tag random other RDBMS. Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Learn what joins do. Every join involves a cross join. Then we keep some rows per ON. Then outer joins add some rows. Then we keep some rows per WHERE. What rows do you want to keep? PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Comment: Hi James. Per your flag, yes, everything stays forever in the edit history. However, mods have a tool that can *redact* sensitive information, which will permanently remove it. That is covered in [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question); see the third bullet point: "If you have posted something super-sensitive...". Note that we don't want to delete the entire question, nor for you to remove *all* the code, as you've done here. That makes the question useless. Instead, you need to *anonymize* it, then reflag for redaction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t2.*, coalesce(t1.location, t1n.location) as location
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.product2 = t1.product1 left join
     table1 t1n
     on t2.product2 = t1n.new_prod_name and t1.product1 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **join conditionally**, but you can join both then conditionally choose the returned values. I don't have any sample data for this, but I'll take a stab at it.

See [complete example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b58a0218eba666590dda787e55c5dcc) here.

```
Select t1_id
     , coalesce(t2.product2,t2n.product2,t1.product1) product
     , t1.location
     , coalesce(t2.quantity,t2n.quantity) product
     , coalesce(t2.adate,t2n.adate) "date"  
  from table1       t1 
  Left join table2  t2 
         on (t2.product2 = t1.product1)  
  left join  table2 t2n
         on (t2n.product2 = t1.new_product_name)
order by t1_id;
```